# Find maximum Euclidean distance of Canny edge output and drawing a line between the points

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am new to Matlab and I am working on a project wherein I want to draw a line between the farthest two  edges of an image.
I have first used Canny edge detection algorithm to get the edges.
Stored the boundaries in a vector.
Then, I have calculated the Euclidean distances amongst all the pixels stored inside the vector.
The problem I am having is storing the maximum value obtained of this Euclidean distance and plotting a line amongst those two pixels.

Here is an example image:
[image]

Code:

```
im = edge(gray,'canny',0.3);
subplot(2,2,3);imshow(im);title('Canny Output');
figure
imagesc(im)
hold on

[B,L] = bwboundaries(im,'noholes');
for l=1:length(B)-1
    for m=l+1:length(B)-1
        for j=1:length(B{l})
            for k=1:length(B{m})
                a(j,k) = abs(B{l}(j,2) - B{m}(k,2));
                b(j,k) = abs(B{l}(j,1) - B{m}(k,1));
                c(j,k) = sqrt(sum(a(j,k)*a(j,k),b(j,k)*b(j,k)));
                [~,idx] = max(c(j,k));
                [x,y] = ind2sub(size(c),idx);
                p1.l = [B{l}(x,2),B{l}(x,1)];
                p2.m = [B{m}(y,2),B{m}(y,1)];
                plot([p1.l(1),p2.m(1)],[p1.l(2),p2.m(2)],'Color','g','LineWidth',2)
                clear a b c x y idx
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: look at [pdist2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html). You may not need 4 `for loops`. Also, you may not require `bwboundaries` function. Just find the coordiates where pixel value=1. Then using pdist2, find the pair of pixels which has the maximum distance.

Comment: @user3262170 do you have a limitation regarding the angle of this line? Are you looking for the the line perpendicular to the center of the vector connecting the two most distant points? Do you consider distance in all possible directions or only vertically and horizontally?

Comment: No limitation for the angle and the max line will be vertical cause the input image is of a ear. @parag If possible can you please write the code I didnt get your point..

Comment: @user3262170 I will not have MATLAB access for at least next 8 hours. Let me ask you a question. How do you define distance between two edges. An edge contains many points. When you say distance between two edges, 1. do you calculate distance between their centroids? 2. maximum/minimum distance between the distances between all the pairs of points?

Comment: @user3262170 it seems that the line you seek will be diagonal in most cases with at least a small inclination. Please provide an image or any other example so that we can see the problem...

Comment: @parag i am checking the maximum distance between all the pairs of points. My aim is to plot a line amongst the two. I guess i have written the code properly but still not getting what i want.

Comment: @sepdek yup slightly diagonal connecting the farthest two boundaries of the ear. Have i messed up with the code? Image i wish i could post but i guess it needs a minimum rep of 10 :(

Comment: @user3262170 send me an email with an image attached and I will post it for you in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly easy to implement in MATLAB and is also fast (at least for small images).
Provided that you have a **binary edge image**, you need to think of white pixels as points in a 2D space and look for the coordinates that correspond to the largest distance.
MATLAB can easily do this using the `pdist2` function with some extra parameters.
Take a look at the following piece of code:

```
img = imread( 'image.bmp');
[ y, x] = find( img);
points = [ x y];
[d,idx] = pdist2( points, points, 'euclidean', 'Largest', 1);
idx1 = idx( d==max(d));
[~,idx2] = find(d==max( d));

p={};
for i=1:length(idx1)
   p{end+1} = [ points(idx1(i),1), points(idx1(i),2), points(idx2(i),1), points(idx2(i),2)];
end
```

First you need to know where are those white pixels so you initiate with a `find` function to get the coordinates. Then you use `pdist2`, which (in this case) returns the largest distances in a row matrix d and the corresponding indices in the row matrix i. Then you just need to check where is the maximum value in the largest distances to get the indices of the points with the maximum distance (these points are in a structure of points `p`). 
If you need to display the results just use the following piece:

```
figure; 
imshow( img);
hold on;
for i=1:numel(p)
    line( [ p{i}(1), p{i}(3)], [p{i}(2), p{i}(4)]);
    hdl = get(gca,'Children');
    set( hdl(1),'LineWidth',2);
    set( hdl(1),'color',[1 0 0]);
end

hold off;
```

You will get this image:
[image: ear image with longest distance]

---

*** an addition that will help keep only unique points:

```
pp=[];
for i=1:numel(p)
    for j=i+1:numel(p)
        if prod( double( [p{i}(3:4),p{i}(1:2)] == p{j}))
            pp(end+1)=j;
        end
    end
end
j=1;
ppp={};
for i=1:numel(p)-numel(pp)
    if j<=numel(pp) && i~=pp(j)
        ppp{end+1}=p{i};
        j=j+1;
    end
end
p = ppp;
```

---

Comment: Be aware that the current implementation only detects the first max distance. If it happens that there are other pixels that produce the same max distance (i.e. other pairs of pixels have the same distance) then you should treat the variable "mdp" as a variable of multiple pairs.

Comment: Wow..thanks a lot..thank you so much! I am pretty new to matlab so had no clue about this. Thanks again! :)

Comment: changed the code a bit, and now it supports multiple max distance lines in case more than one pair of points correspond to the maximum distance. There was also a problem in the indexing...you will probably need to take care of situations with multiples of the same points in p structure.